# PySpark : How to duplicate the rows of a dataframe based on the values in one column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

From a simple dataframe like that in PySpark :

```
col1    col2    count
A       1       4
A       2       8
A       3       2
B       1       3
C       1       6
```

I would like to duplicate the rows in order to have each value of col1 with each value of col2 and the column count filled with 0 for those we don't have the original value. It would be like that :

```
col1    col2    count
A       1       4
A       2       8
A       3       2
B       1       3
B       2       0
B       3       0
C       1       6
C       2       0
C       3       0
```

Do you have any idea how to do that efficiently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `crossJoin`.

```
data = df.select('col1', 'col2')
// this one gives you all combinations of col1+col2
all_combinations = data.alias('a').crossJoin(data.alias('b')).select('a.col1', 'b.col2')
// this one will append with count column from original dataset, and null for all other records.
all_combinations.alias('a').join(df.alias('b'), on=(col(a.col1)==col(b.col1) & col(a.col2)==col(b.col2)), how='left').select('a.*', b.count)
```

Comment: Thanks, crossJoin is definitely what I was looking for !